# xcode 8.0 "add the Push Notif(..) to your App ID" warning, while already added

Tags: ios, xcode, push-notification, provisioning-profile

- I have Xcode managing provisioning profiles (recommended
  'automatic' setting)
- **My app id already contains the Push**
- When I launch Xcode it shows the Push capabilities with checkmarks,
  as if everything was fine
- When I register device token and push a message, I get
  notRegistered response from GCM. But when I update the profiles
  Settings>Profile>View Details>Download all profiles the above
  mentioned checkbox turns into red warning sign.

This seems to be an Xcode bug. Anybody has a workaround?

[image]

Comment: Can you please file a bug at bugreporter.apple.com? Please include any entitlements files and a copy of the "Update signing" log in the Reports navigator.

Comment: I did, they didn't get back to me. This was a bug, I have created new project, repeated all steps and it worked. I believe this was related to keychain certificates not being properly synchronised with xcode.

Answer (score 0):

refer this link

https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/68101

when you create distribution certificate that this you should Enable push notification feature for your app.

sorry for my english

Answer (score 0):

For Your develoepr account You must Enable APNS in App Ids. Check below screen shot.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try restarting Xcode. If this did not work, then do the following:

You need to download a provision profile:

1) Go to https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/profile/limited/ Select the project => edit => Certificates => Select All => Create => Download

or if you already have a profile

Go to https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/profile/limited/
Select your project => Edit => Generate => Download

2) In Xcode:
Unclick Automatically manage signing.

[image]

Import provisioning profile:
Project file => Signing (Debug) => Provisioning profile => Import profile => Select file with 1