# Add the Push Notifications feature to your App ID Error

Tags: ios, iphone, apple-push-notifications

I made app id on apple developer account with push notification enabled 
[image]

On xcode project i am getting sign in status with following messages
[image]

On target >capabilities i have following message 
[image]

How i can resolve this issue?
I have read these answers but issue persist

[Report error in Step:Add the Push Notifications feature to your App ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41220355/report-error-in-stepadd-the-push-notifications-feature-to-your-app-id)

[xcode 8.0 "add the Push Notif(..) to your App ID" warning, while already added](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39649813/xcode-8-0-add-the-push-notif-to-your-app-id-warning-while-already-added)

Answer (score 1):

Try restarting Xcode. If this did not work, then do the following:

You need to download a provision profile:

1) Go to https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/profile/limited/ Select the project => edit => Certificates => Select All => Create => Download

or if you already have a profile

Go to https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/profile/limited/
Select your project => Edit => Generate => Download

2) In Xcode:
Unclick Automatically manage signing.

[image]

Import provisioning profile:
Project file => Signing (Debug) => Provisioning profile => Import profile => Select file with 1

Comment: Thanks this save my day!!

Answer (score 0):

Fixed my bundle identifier and it worked